# left outer join returning multiple records

Tags: mysql

The below query is returning duplicate/multiple records. Is there a way the second left join performed on distinct IDs of SW.MTableId.

```
SELECT SW.* from
(SELECT * FROM Stable SD,MTable MT WHERE SD.ID=1234 AND SD.ID=MT.Stable_ID) SW  
LEFT OUTER JOIN TTable TD ON (TD.MTable_ID=SW.MTableId AND TD.STATUS='ACTIVE') 
LEFT OUTER JOIN PTable PT ON (PT.MTable_ID=SW.MTableId AND PT.TTable_ID IS NULL) 
enter code here
```

Duplicate rows:

```
SW.MTableId TD.MTable_ID  PT.MTable_ID 
71878        67048         849230
71878        67046         849230
71878        67047         849230
71878        67039         849230
71878        67038         849230
71878        67045         849230
71878        67037         849230
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/5a127b/2  Have created a fiddle with complete table definitions, the requirement is we need a query to get the primary key columns from each table.

```
Stable can be direct parent of Ftable, Ttable, Etable, Rtable.
Ftable can be direct parent of Ttable, Etable only.
Ttable can be direct parent of Etable, Rtable.
Etable can be direct parent of Rtable.
```

#Expected Result

```
Sid  Fid  Tid  Eid  Rid
2    12   103  203  303
2    12   103  203  304
1    null 101  null 302 
3    null null null 301
1    10   null 202  null
1    null null 201  null  
1    null 102  null null
1    11   null null

Stable
sid, sname
1,   'S1'
2,   's2'
3,   's3'

Ftable
fid, fname, sid
10,  'f1',  1
11,  'f2',  1
12,  'f3',  2

Ttable
tid, tname, fid,  sid
101, 't1',  null, 1
102, 't2',  null, 1
103, 't3',  12,   2

Etable
eid, ename, tid , fid, sid
201, 'e1',  null, null, 1
202, 'e2',  null, 10,   1
203, 'e3',  103,  12,   2

Rtable 
(rid, rname eid  tid  sid)
(301, 'r1'  null null 3) 
(302, 'r2'  null 101  1)
(304, 'r4'  203, 103  2)
(303, 'r3'  203, 103  2)
```

Comment: I don't really understand the query, but maybe you could use a group by statement.
For example: 
`SELECT SW.* from
(SELECT * FROM Stable SD,MTable MT WHERE SD.ID=1234 AND SD.ID=MT.Stable_ID) SW  
LEFT OUTER JOIN TTable TD ON (TD.MTable_ID=SW.MTableId AND TD.STATUS='ACTIVE') 
LEFT OUTER JOIN PTable PT ON (PT.MTable_ID=SW.MTableId AND PT.TTable_ID IS NULL) 
GROUP BY SW.MTableId`

Comment: Include example data. Show which table can have multiple rows for the same id/key. Where there are multiple rows show m the logic for which single row to choose. For the included example data, show the exact result you require.

Comment: Have updated the main question with data

Comment: What you mean by `second left join performed on distinct IDs of SW.MTableId.`. driving query is  SW and you will get the number of rows returned by SW any how so the left join will lead duplicate (as you say) only when there are multiple records for `SW.MTableId`. and my second doubt is,  what is the use of two left joins if you don't need to select anything from them. I am not sure but you may need `exists` rather `left join`

Comment: @Sujitmohanty30 - We need columns from PTable hence it is joined. But could see the correct result when we do separate join ' LEFT OUTER JOIN TTable ON SW' and "LEFT OUTER JOIN PTable PT ON SW" and do union all. But, we want to achieve in one query.

Comment: If I understood the problem this is not really duplicate but this is how the join works but my question is what you want to show from `PT` and `DT` ? The result you posted is not duplicate as `TD.MTable_ID` are different. What happens under the hood is if you have 3 records in `TD` and 2 records in `PT` for the same `SW.MTableId` the no of rows will be 3*2 which is a cross product of both left join.  Could you post full output and what you want to show from `TD` and `PT` ?

Comment: Never use comma/implicit style joins, and definitely don't intermingle implicit and explicit join syntax. For further help, see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: @Sujitmohanty30 I have added fiddle. Can you please take a look at it. And the relation ship between the tables are the below. We only need a query with primary keys of all columns like (Sid, Fid, Tid, Eid, Rid)

Comment: Please provide sample data *inside* the question for each table, and the corresponding(!) expected output.

Comment: @trincot data available in fiddle and have updated expected result in main question

Comment: Data should not be behind a link. Please edit it inside your question.

Comment: @trincot have updated the sample data

Comment: Looks like  `sid` and `fid` are sometimes mixed up.

Comment: Your sample output **does not show** duplicate rows. The values of `TD.MTable_ID` are unique. If this is not the result you expect, perhaps you need additional logic, to select maybe the maximum or minimum value of `TD.MTable_ID`?

Comment: @trincot Yes. Have corrected now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- You want all rows from rtable and all rows from etable.
- You want those rows from ttable that don't have a match in these previous two tables.
- You want those rows from ftable that don't have a match in these previous three tables.
- You want those rows from stable that don't have a match in these previous four tables.

And you consider null a value, i.e. you consider null = null a match.

Here is the query doing this step by step.

```
select sid, null as fid, tid, eid, rid from rtable
union all
select sid, fid, tid, eid, null as rid from etable
union all
select sid, fid, tid, null as eid, null as rid from ttable
  where (sid, coalesce(fid, -1), coalesce(tid, -1)) not in 
    (select sid, coalesce(fid, -1), coalesce(tid, -1) from etable)
  and (sid, coalesce(fid, -1), coalesce(tid, -1)) not in 
    (select sid, -1, coalesce(tid, -1) from rtable)
union all
select sid, fid, null as tid, null as eid, null as rid from ftable
  where (sid, coalesce(fid, -1)) not in
    (select sid, coalesce(fid, -1) from ttable)
  and (sid, coalesce(fid, -1)) not in
    (select sid, coalesce(fid, -1) from etable)
  and (sid, coalesce(fid, -1)) not in
    (select sid, -1 from rtable)
union all
select sid, null as fid, null as tid, null as eid, null as rid from stable
  where sid not in (select sid from ftable)
  and sid not in (select sid from ttable)
  and sid not in (select sid from etable)
  and sid not in (select sid from rtable)
order by sid, fid, tid, eid, rid;
```

The result is almost the one you have requested. Only, you merge rows of rtable and etable for sid 2 and I don't know why. Well, if this is what you need, you can probably alter my query accordingly.

Demo: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ae1a69/1